# Finding corners in a 2d map with walls

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, image-processing

I'm working on an AI for the aisandbox.com competition. I'm making the AI for fun, not to enter the competition (just in case I would be breaking rules by asking here if I was).

I can get a 2d map of the area by using `self.level.blockHeights`, and I want to find some places where my bots can hide by finding corners in the map and having them defend there.

So my question is, given a 2d array of numbers where 0 is free space and 1 is a wall, what's the best way of finding corners?

P.s. I'm using Python

EDIT: here's an example of a map (the walls are black) and the corners to be found are in red:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by corners ? Could you give a simple example of a small grid and highlight the corners ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your example grid, it would seem a **corner** can be defined by `0` *that is surrounded by at least 2* `1`.

You could begin by writing this definition in a dumb implementation at first (like I did below intentionally), and then maybe improve it by thinking about performance, for example.

`2` represents a corner in this implementation

**Example Python implementation**:

```
g = [[1,1,1,0],
     [1,0,0,0],
     [1,0,0,0],
     [1,0,1,0],
     [1,1,1,1]]

width = len(g[0])
height = len(g)

for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        if g[i][j] != 0:
            continue
        around = [(i-1,j),(i+1,j),(i,j-1),(i,j+1)]
        walls = 0
        for (x,y) in around:
            if x < 0 or x >= height or y < 0 or y >= width:
                #Outside, count as wall
                walls += 1
            elif g[x][y] == 1:
                walls += 1
        if walls in [2,3]: # 4 would be inaccessible  
            g[i][j] = 2
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far are extremely slow (although their complexity is linear) - particularly in python, since they involve extensive looping. Also, they're not very robust to noise (though I understand that's not required here)

A nice trick to solving this problem (if you're willing to use scipy and numpy) is to apply a [gaussian filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html) with a small kernel to the image and subtract the original image from it (taking care not to underflow). Since the corners "bleed" more into the background, in the resulting image the corners will be the pixels with highest intensity.

Here's an actual example:

```
import numpy
import scipy.ndimage
import scipy.misc

image= scipy.ndimage.imread('corners.png').astype(float)
image= numpy.mean( image, axis=2) #squash color channels
filtered=   scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(image,1)
subtracted= (256+image)-filtered #take care not to underflow
maximum, minimum=   numpy.max(subtracted), numpy.min(subtracted)
magic= 0.48 #will depend on source image. Fool around and see what works
threshold= (maximum+minimum)/2+(maximum-minimum)*magic 
thresholded= subtracted>=threshold

print list(zip(*numpy.where(thresholded)))
```

outputs `[(190, 206), (207, 314)]`

corners.png:

[image: corners.png]

filtered:

[image: filtered]

thresolded:

[image: thresolded]

Comment: Nice technique, I am keeping the other answer as the accepted answer since this one is less suitable. I like the linear simple approach as it's very easy to implement across different languages and time isn't a factor. Thanks a lot though, this is very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

From your example, one could define corners as free cells with two adjacent cells occupied by walls, the two occupied cells in a configuration North/East, North/West, South/East and South/West.

Therefore finding corners is just a matter of scanning your 2D map and look at the adjacent cell of every free cell.

I am assuming that you don't want free cells with 3 surrounding walls (like in the end of a corridor).

Assuming that you have a function `isWall(x,y)`:

```
def isCorner(x, y) :
     eastHasWall = isWall(x+1, y)
     westHasWall = isWall(x-1, y)
     northHasWall = isWall(x, y-1)
     southHasWall = isWall(x, y+1)

     wallArray = [eastHasWall, westHasWall, northHasWall, southHasWall]
     wallCount = wallArray.count(true)

     if wallCount == 2 :
         return (eastHasWall and northHasWall) or (eastHasWall and southHasWall) or (westHasWall and northHasWall) or (westHasWall and southHasWall)

     return false # other wall count are not corners
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should compile.

One should also be careful with the boundaries of the map. Only you can say if they are considered as walls or as free space in your settings.

Comment: ..with two or three adjacent cells... since you could have a "one pixel corridor" (and the corner would be at the end of that corridor)

Comment: From the question, it was impossible to say if the "end of a one pixel corridor" was considered a corner or not. I am assuming it is not the case, but it is easy to amend my code if it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code

```
function isCorner(x, y) {
    wallsFound = 0;
    if (withinBounds(x + 1, y) && grid[x + 1][y] == 1)
        wallsFound++
    if (withinBounds(x - 1, y) && grid[x - 1][y] == 1)
        wallsFound++
    if (withinBounds(x, y + 1) && grid[x][y + 1] == 1)
        wallsFound++
    if (withinBounds(x, y - 1) && grid[x][y - 1] == 1)
        wallsFound++
    return wallsFound  == 2 || wallsFound == 3;
}

function withinBounds(x, y) {
    return x >= 0
        && x < rows.len
        && y >= 0
        && y < cols.len
}

for i = 0 to rows.len
    for j = 0 to cols.len
        if isCorner(x, y)
            // do something
```

You could change `&&` to `||` in isCorner if you want the edge of the map to count as a wall.